# Get root path of a tree with pure MySQL

Tags: mysql, path, tree, root

I want to get path from node to root of a tree. This is my tree for example:

```
id  |   name    |   parent_id
------------------------------
1   |   mike    |   0
2   |   danny   |   1
3   |   peter   |   1
4   |   clark   |   2
5   |   lily    |   1
6   |   stefan  |   3
7   |   simon   |   3
8   |   boby    |   1
9   |   john    |   4
10  |   elly    |   4
```

I write an algoritm with php and mysql but it is slowly

```
public function GetRootPath($a_id) {
    $root="";
    $results="";
    while(1==1){
        $result = DB::select("SELECT id, parent_id FROM users WHERE id=$a_id");
        if($result[0]->refr!=0) {
               if($root==""){
                   $root=$result[0]->parent_id;
               }
               else {
                   $root=$result[0]->parent_id.'.'.$root;
               } 
            $a_id=$result[0]->parent_id;
        }
       else {
           break;
       }
    }
    return $root;
}
```

How could this be written in pure MySQL? I'm not very aware with MySQL procedures and functions.

Comment: Maybe switch to a nested set

Comment: nested set is good for trees with fixed depth, mines is very dynamic (referral system).

Comment: Why is a nested set good for trees with fixed depth? I would have thought that the opposite was true !?!?!

Comment: Because you will have to write new left and right values everytime, when new child is set, as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think stored procedures could work:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_root;
CREATE PROCEDURE get_root(
   IN parentID INT,
   OUT rootID INT
)

BEGIN   
    SELECT parent_id FROM tree WHERE id = parentID INTO rootID;

    IF rootID = 0
        THEN SET rootID = parentID;
    ELSE
        CALL get_root(rootID, rootID);
    END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;

SET @@GLOBAL.max_sp_recursion_depth = 255;
SET @@session.max_sp_recursion_depth = 255; 

CALL get_root(4, @rootID);
SELECT @rootID;
```

Comment: It's working with some fixes, `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_root;` must be before `DELIMITER $$`, this MySQL language is a bitch. One question - why do you set @@GLOBAL and @@session max_sp_recursion_depth, what is the difference, isn't @@session enough?

Comment: The truth is when I saw your question I didn't knew the answer but it seems so interesting for me that I've tried to solve it.

So, doing some research I've got this answer. It's true that with @@session could be enough but I assume that then this procedure only will work on the same session. If you want to call it on any session I think you should use @@GLOBAL