# SQL own sort order

Tags: sql, sorting

How to sort values (rows with 2 elements) whereby the second colum is the link to the previous row/first column whereby the values are numeric but not sortable on a normal numeric value order/calculated one, example:

```
1 - 0   no previous row
3 - 1   1 in second colum refers to 1 in previous row in first column
4 - 3   3 in second colum refers to 3 in previous row in first column
2 - 4   ... 
9 - 2
7 - 9
5 - 7
6 - 5
8 - 6
```

sort result should be: 1 - 3 - 4 - 2 - 9 - 7 - 5 - 6 - 8

The tricky part is the unknown sequence, so case, decode, if, ... can't be included because the values are unknown (the only one who is known is the first row by 0 in the second column)

Does someone has already solved such a sortorder?

Comment: Tag the database you are using

Comment: What you're asking can be thought of as a tree problem, and tree-specific SQL varies by vendor. For MySQL, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27579716/get-root-path-of-a-tree-with-pure-mysql In addition, answers to similar questions have found the following helpful: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #t (
  valor int null
, valor2 int null
, linha int not null identity
)

insert into #t (valor) values (1)
insert into #t (valor) values (3)
insert into #t (valor) values (4)
insert into #t (valor) values (2)
insert into #t (valor) values (9)
insert into #t (valor) values (7)
insert into #t (valor) values (5)
insert into #t (valor) values (6)
insert into #t (valor) values (8)

update #t set #t.valor2 = isnull(t2.valor, 0)
  from (
  select valor, linha +1 as linha
    from #t
  ) t2
 where #t.linha = t2.linha

 select valor, valor2, linha from #t order by linha

 select valor, isnull(valor2, 0) as valor2 from #t order by 2

 drop table #t
```

The result is something like:

[image: First result ordered by the numbers input, and the second is the final result]